# python sort a list of strings based on substrings using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have an excel sheet with 4 columns, Filename, SNR, Dynamic Range, Level.

| Filename | SNR | Dynamic Range | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS8**_HPOF.xlsx | 5 | 11 | 8 |
| 19___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS32**_HPOF.xlsx | 15 | 31 | 23 |
| 10___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS16**_HPOF.xlsx | 10 | 21 | 24 |
| 28___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS48**_HPOF.xlsx | 20 | 41 | 23 |
| 37___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS8**_HP4.xlsx | 25 | 51 | 12 |

I need to reorganize the first column of the table, Xls filename, such that the bolded part is in order from least to greatest.
i.e.

| Filename | SNR | Dynamic Range | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS8**_HPOF.xlsx | 5 | 11 | 8 |
| 37___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS8**_HP4.xlsx | 25 | 51 | 12 |
| 10___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS16**_HPOF.xlsx | 10 | 21 | 24 |
| 19___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS32**_HPOF.xlsx | 15 | 31 | 23 |
| 28___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_**FS48**_HPOF.xlsx | 20 | 41 | 23 |

I don't want to change the actual excel file. I was hoping to use pandas because I am doing some other manipulation later on.

I tried this

```
df.sort_values(by='Xls Filename', key=lambda col: col.str.contains('_FS'),ascending=True)
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Extract the pattern, find the sort index using `argsort` and then sort with the sort index:

```
# extract the number to sort by into a Series
fs = df.Filename.str.extract('FS(\d+)_\w+\.xlsx$', expand=False)

# find the sort index using `argsort` and reorder data frame with the sort index
df.loc[fs.astype(int).argsort()]

#                                                                       Filename  ...  Level
#0    1___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_FS8_HPOF.xlsx  ...      8
#4    37___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_FS8_HP4.xlsx  ...     12
#2  10___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_FS16_HPOF.xlsx  ...     24
#1  19___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_FS32_HPOF.xlsx  ...     23
#3  28___SLATE_FPGA_BESBEV_TX_AMIC_9.6MHz_Normal_IN1_G0_0_HQ_DEC0_FS48_HPOF.xlsx  ...     23
```

Where regex `FS(\d+)_\w+\.xlsx$` will capture digits that immediately follow `FS` and precede `_\w+\.xlsx`.

---

In case you might have patterns that don't match, convert to float instead of int due to possible `nan`s:

```
df.loc[fs.astype(float).values.argsort()]
```

Comment: Great. Glad it helps !